# Creating a trigger in Oracle that inserts or updates a table whilst keeping the old records intact

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have one main table and a series of smaller less significant tables, in Oracle Database. For the purposes of this question I will refer to this table as `The_Main_Table`. `The_Main_Table` needs to keep records of all previous information regarding food product sales as well as some product information. I have a table called the `Sales_Table` which has information regarding these sales.

The columns that are shared between both `The_Main_Table` and `Sales_Table` are labelled as follows:

```
PRODUCT_ID
SALES_SEASON
SALES_DATE
BRANCH
LOCATION
```

I need  a trigger on `The_Main_Table` that works so that once the `Sales_Table` is either updated or a new row is inserted into the `Sales_Table`, that this change is reflected in `The_Main_Table`. However, I also need a copy of the original rows for this `Product_ID` to be kept for historical data queries. The remaining columns that are not shared by both `The_Main_Table` and `The_Sales_Table` should be unchanged.

Thank you for taking the time to read this question, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This copy of the original rows, do you want to keep it in THE_MAIN_TABLE or in a separate archive table? That decision is key to implementing this.

Comment: One way to do this is to perform insert trigger on main_table when any row updated in sales _table, but there will be row redundancy in main_table, if you keep adding new rows in main_table for each update.

Comment: @APC The copy of the original rows needs to be stored inside The_Main_Table :)

Comment: Why do the original rows "need" to be stored inside the main table?  keeping only the current data there, and using a 'history table' to keep all previous versions of the data is the typical and normal way of dealing with this.  Your "need" strongly suggests you need a re-think of your design.  Also, your tables are not "in Oracle SQL Developer"  They are in a database.  SQL Dev is merely one of many possible client programs for accessing that data base.

Comment: Do you have an existing way to indicate which rows in The_Main_Table are historical and which ones are current? E.g. a sequence number, a Y/N "is_current" flag, a timestamp, etc?

Comment: It looks like he has a products that can be used for multiple sales seasons and the update would be to a new season or if a product moves location during the same sales season. Can you share the primary key of the Main Table? I suspect that it is product ID alone. I echo the sentiments earlier that there should be another table with the historical data made, and then a view union-ing the two tables for your historical reports.